# How to use handler404 view in django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I want to display a 404 error page when user hits a url which is not in the urls.py. 
In settings.py I put DEBUG = False,and I have written a handler view like this

```
def handler404(request):
  from django.shortcuts import render
  return render(request, '404.html')
```

and in urls.py I have included

handler404 = 'myapp.handlerview'

Now whenever I am entering a url which is not in the urls list then I am getting 500 server error.I want to display 404.html page instead of 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do any of this. It is, of course, Django's default behaviour to return the 404 page if it does not match any of the URLs in the urlconf.

The default handler is almost always suitable, you just need to define a template called `404.html` in the root of your templates directory. The only reason to define a custom handler is if you need extra context variables, or if you want to do custom logic (eg logging) on a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you did not include an exception argument to the handler.

Instead of

```
def handler404(request):
  from django.shortcuts import render
  return render(request, '404.html')
```

It needs to be

```
def handler404(request, exception):
  from django.shortcuts import render
  return render(request, '404.html')
```

Please refer to the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404